# How to tell if a stampede is a reason to leave?

Tags: resignation

I work for a company where in the past week out of about 130 employees, 10 announced their departures and in prior weeks people were leaving as well. I am wondering if I should be joining the stampede out the door.

How do you figure out if you should join the stampede?

Comment: Do you hate your job? No? Don't leave

Answer (score 8):

The important thing is to understand *why* that group of employees left. Are there systemic issues in your company that you haven’t seen yet? Did they suffer some injustice from the company? Did they get picked off to join another company? Did they all have new jobs lined up?

If you uncover problems at your company while thinking about these questions, consider leaving. If you don’t, consider staying.

Comment: It would be nice to understand why that group of employees left, but in practice you will never know.  You may not even know whether they were fired or if they quit.  This might be unannounced mass layoffs.

Comment: Man, I was hoping the answer that said this would've phrased it as "Figure out what spooked the herd"   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't "join" anything, or leave a job only because others have chosen to leave.

If there are elements of your job that you're not happy with (and you think you can find another job that would be better for you) then apply for other jobs and interview for them. Leave your current job **only** if you get a better offer.